# Related to the classification theorem for compact surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, triangulation

I am reading Massey's Algebraic Topology: An Introduction. Theorem 5.1 (the classification theorem for compact surfaces) of chapter 1 has a couple of steps. The whole proof is algorithmic. In the first step, the triangulation of a compact surface is given (without the proof of the existence). I understand the whole proof/algorithm except the claim of step 3 of the proof.

In step 3, the author says we can transform our polygon such that all vertices are identified to a single point. At some point in the proof of this step, he says that we can completely eliminate a class of vertices. (By the way, the vertices are to be equivalent iff they are to be identified.)

Can anyone please explain how we can eventually eliminate a certain class of vertices? Thank you so much.

Comment: I haven't read Massey's book but I'm sure you could find a more rigorous proof (which I guess is what you're looking for) in Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* which uses CW-Complexes to classify compact surfaces.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look at Lee's book. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! Lee's book is wonderful for rigorous proofs on (basic) algebraic topology. Rotman's book *Introuction to Algebraic Topology* is the most *rigorous* book I've seen on algebraic topology and explains everything concretely, so you could also take a look at that if you want (though I don't recall it classifying compact surfaces)

Comment: The polygon gluing proof basically *is* the CW complex proof. And I would not say that this proof is about algebraic topology, its really just about manipulating quotient spaces.

Comment: Hi... Do you remember how the author eliminate the case such as $aba^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}d^{-1}cdefe^{-1}f^{-1}$, in which contains forms like $c^{-1}d^{-1}cd$... Seems the author hasn't explain this...

Comment: I post my question and I would appreciate if you can help me: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583221/proof-of-classification-theorem-for-compact-surfaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me use $P$ to denote the polygon. Suppose also that there are two or more equivalence classes of vertices. It follows that if you start at one vertex and then walk one at a time around the vertices of $P$, there must exist two consecutive vertices $V_1,V_2$ which are in different classes. Let $E$ be the edge of $P$ having endpoints $V_1,V_2$. This edge $E$ is identified with some other edge that I'll denote $E'$. Under the identification of $E$ with $E'$, $V_1$ is identified with one endpoint of $E'$ denoted $V'_1$, and $V_2$ is identified with the opposite endpoint of $E'$ denoted $V'_2$. The vertices $V_1,V_2$ are in the same class, and the vertices $V'_1,V'_2$ are in the same class which is different from the $V_1,V_2$ class.

Now alter $P$, taking a quotient by collapsing $E$ to a point and simultaneously collapsing $E'$ to a point, producing a new polygon $P'$ with two fewer sides, and the side pairing of $P$ induces a side pairing of $P'$ which produces the same surface (there's something to think about to convince yourself that it produces the same surface up to homeomorphism).

Of key importance is that this operation has the effect of reducing the number of equivalence classes of vertices by $1$: the $V_1,V_2$ class and the $V'_1,V'_2$ class have been merged into a single class; and the other equivalence classes of vertices remain intact.

For an example of this, take a regular hexagon in the plane and glue each pair of parallel sides, choosing the gluing map to be the Euclidean translation. Check that there are exactly two equivalence classes of vertices, with 3 vertices in each class, and the endpoints of each edge being in different classes. You may now choose any one of the opposite side pairs to be $E$ and $E'$, and you may take a quotient by simultaneously collapsing $E$ and $E'$ to get a square. You may then check that the induced gluing on that square is the standard gluing for a torus.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think the last example summarizes the whole issue. Thanks a lot. Thanks for the details.

Comment: Glad to be of help. By the way, I notice that you have not accepted any answers to your questions so far. The standard practice on this site is that you choose an acceptable answer to your question, if there is one, and you click on the check mark to accept that answer. That gives some reputation points to the person whose answer you accepted, thereby providing a reward and a motivation for people to answer questions. It helps to make the site work well when you do that.

Comment: Professor Lee, First of all, I'm sorry. I did not know how to accept an answer. Now, I know it. Thank you for your clarification. I guess you also understood that I did not know this idea of accepting an answer. Thank you again.