# Proof of classification theorem for compact surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, compact-manifolds

I am reading Massey's 'A basic coruse in Algebraic Topology'. In first chapter, he proved classification theorem for compact surfaces (compact connected 2-manifold). This theorem classifies compact surfaces into 3 cases: sphere ($aa^{-1}$), connected sum of tori (e.g. $aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1}$) and connected sum of projective planes (e.g $aabbccdd$).

I try to read over the proof. There is one question which the author seems hasn't explained in this book. How to deal with the case for example $aba^{-1}b^{-1}e^{-1}f^{-1}efcdc^{-1}d^{-1}$ which contains something like  $e^{-1}f^{-1}ef$, but not $efe^{-1}f^{-1}$?

Comment: Note that $e^{-1}f^{-1}ef = e^{-1}f^{-1}(e^{-1})^{-1}(f^{-1})^{-1}$.

Comment: OK,,,, seems I understand....

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese  So do you mean the case $aba^{-1}b^{-1}e^{-1}f^{-1}ef$ is same to the $aba^{-1}b^{-1}efe^{-1}f^{-1}f$? Seems right to me, but I cannot convince myself...

Comment: No, I mean the case $aba^{-1}b^{-1}e^{-1}f^{-1}ef$ is the same as $aba^{-1}b^{-1}ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ (I have labelled $e^{-1}$ by $g$ and $f^{-1}$ by $h$). The latter is something dealt with by Massey.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Emmm, on Massey's book P13, he says 'Starting at a definite vertex, proceed around the boundary of the polygon...if the arrow on a side points in the same direction that we are going around the boundary then we write the letter for that side with exponent +1. If it is opposite direction, then assign -1. So, if you replace $e^{-1}f^{-1}ef$ with $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$, then you change the direction...

Comment: Sure, but once you came to the fifth side, you had to introduce a new label (it didn't correspond to $a$, $b$, $a^{-1}$, or $b^{-1}$). Why are you giving it the name $e^{-1}$?